# Subtraction of multiples of a partition from itself

Tags: co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics, partitions

**Definitions:**

By a *partition*, I will mean a finite multi-set of positive integers. We denote this by $[s_1^{p_1}, ..., s_n^{p_n}]$ where $s_n$ are the associated integers and $p_n$ the multiplicity of $s_n$ in the partition.

Given a partition $P$, we denote by $|P|$ the sum $\sum_{i = 1}^n p_i$, that is, the total number of integers in the partition counted with multiplicity.

We may also denote a partition by a finite list of integers $\{a_k\}$, where the $a_k$ are just the integers in the partition, counted with multiplicity.

Given a partition $P = [s_1^{p_1}, ..., s_n^{p_n}]$, and a positive integer $n$, we denote by $kP$ the $k$-fold duplication of $P$ - that is, the partition $[s_1^{kp_1}, ..., s_n^{kp_n}]$.

Given two partitions $P = \{a_k\}$ and $Q = \{b_j\}$ with $|Q| \leq |P|$, denote by $P - Q$ the set consisting of all partitions of the form

$\{a_{\phi (1)} - b_{\psi (1)} \ , \ \cdots \ , \ a_{\phi (|Q|)} - b_{\psi (|Q|)} \ , \ a_{\phi (|Q| + 1)}\, , \cdots , a_{\phi (|P|)}\}$

for permutations $\phi$ and $\psi$ such that $a_{\phi (i)} \geq b_{\psi (i)}$ for all $i = 1,\dots, |Q|$.

Given two sets of partitions $\mathcal P$ and $\mathcal Q$, denote by $\mathcal P - \mathcal Q$ the set $\bigcup_{P \in \mathcal P, Q \in \mathcal Q, |P| \geq |Q|} P - Q$. By abuse of notation we will write a set $\{P\}$ consisting of a single partition as just $P$.

**Question set up:**

Let $n > 1$ be a positive integer, and let $k_1, \dots, k_m$ be positive integers such that $\sum k_i < n$. Let $P$ be a partition.

> **Question:** In terms of $P$, $n$, and $k_i$, what is $nP - k_1P - \dots - k_mP$?

**Remarks**:

Of particular interest to me are the cases:

- $m = 1$, $k_1 = k$ for some $k < n$.
- $m = M$, $k_1, \dots, k_M = 1$ for some $M < n$.

The case $m = 1$, $k_1 = n-1$ is (implicitly) addressed in the thread [Quotient groups obtained by quotienting $G^n$ by $G^{n-1}$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/392357/quotient-groups-obtained-by-quotienting-gn-by-gn-1/392380#392380) by David E Speyer.

Comment: It looks like $$(P-Q)-R=(P-R)-Q=P-(Q+R),$$ doesn't it?

Comment: The first should be true, but the latter is not, surprisingly. This can be seen if you take $P = [1^1, 5^1]$, say. Then $3P - P - P$ contains $[1^3, 3^1]$, but $3P - 2P$ does not.

Comment: Or rather I should say - $+$ could be defined so as to make that formula true, but it’s not in general true that $2P = P + P$.